# Accessing elements of an array within object of object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, wikipedia-api

I am trying to access information such as name and logo in the Infobox company section returned when a search is performed using the code below. I've used an example of google. 
If the exit command is removed it can be seen that I can access contentformat and contentmodel in the [0] object however I am struggling to access anything in the [*] array within this object. Forgive the silly question, as I'm sure I'm missing something but any assistance is most appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="google" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$search = $_POST['q'];


$url_2 = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=$search&rvsection=0&continue=";
$res_2 = file_get_contents($url_2);
$data_2 = json_decode($res_2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data_2);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
?>

<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $search; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data_2->query->pages as $r): 

?>

<li>

<?php echo $r->revisions[0]->contentformat;  ?>

</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>

<?php 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: don't use Wikipedia as a database, instead use Wikidata.org which is its own database.

Docs: http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetclaims

Example (Google logo): http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q95&property=P154&format=json >

```
{"claims":{"P154":[{"id":"Q95$49959725-4b36-6a53-b0ef-79bc19a2474c","mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P154","datatype":"commonsMedia","datavalue":{"value":"Logo Google 2013 Official.svg","type":"string"}},...}}}
```

If you need to find the entity ID and you know the article name in one Wikipedia language, [pywikibot can help](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Wikidata#Working_with_pywikibot.2Fcore_.28former_rewrite_branch.29): it will be something like

```
page = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Douglas Adams')
```

and you can continue from there.

Comment: Do you know of any easy way to find the entity value?

Comment: @Oroku, let me add it to my answer.